# Get all descendants of given XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I want to get all the children from given node till leaves without using recursion. Is that possible? I know how to do it in LINQ to XML, but have some problems with XmlNode:S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`SelectNodes` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx) along with an XPath expression that selects all descendants:

```
XmlNodeList result = myXmlNode.SelectNodes("descendant::node()");
```

Make sure to use the [other overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9.aspx) if you want to filter more specifically and need to supply any namespace prefixes.

**Update:** This will only select non-attribute nodes as your question doesn't ask for attributes. It's possible by modifying the XPath expression, though:

```
XmlnodeList result = myXmlNode.SelectNodes("descendant::node() | descendant::*/@*");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use recursion or an XPath expression:

I'm not very good at XPath but something like:

```
 var nodes = myDoc.SelectNodes("//*");
```

(edit: this one seems to work)

Comment: Only for elements, though. Other kinds of nodes will not be selected by `*`.

Comment: Also, have you tried this from an arbitrary node in the middle of the document, or just from the root node? I didn't and the documentation wasn't explicit on this, but usually `//` means that everything from the root is considered, not just the current subtree.